# What does it mean to evaluate an integral over a volume?

Tags: integration

I have a homework problem where I need to evaluate an integral and my calculus skills are really rusty.

> **The problem:**
> Evaluate the following integral
> $$\int r^3z^2\mathrm{d}V$$
> over a volume defined by a cylinder of legth $L$ and radius $R$, oriented along the $z$-axis and centered at the origin. 
> **Hint:** first integrate over a circle and then integrate along the $z$-axis.

Honestly, I'm confused by the language of the problem. What does it mean to evaluate the integral over a volume, and what does it represent? I know the equation of the volume of a cylinder, but what do I do with that formula and the given equation $r^3 z^2$. How do I relate the two to start to solve the problem?

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws0mA.png)

Comment: Well what do you think it means to integrate a function $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ between two points $a$ and $b$??

Comment: First questions: have you heard of multiple integrals ? Have you heard of the "element of volume" ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are asked to integrate a function over the volume of the region, please use the same bounds for your triple integral that you would, to find the volume of the region. In this case it is a cylinder of length $L$ and radius $R$ oriented along $z-$axis and with center at the origin.

So, $0 \leq r \leq R, -\frac{L}{2} \leq z \leq \frac{L}{2}$.

In cylindrical coordinates, $dV = r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$

So your integral is $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int_0^R  r^4 z^2 \ r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta $.